# Double Switch Method gone wild?

Tags: java

here is the method class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Methods extends Basic {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    public void Nome(){
        String name = keyboard .nextLine();
       System.out.println("what is your name");
       switch(name){
       case "john":
           if(name.length() < 5){
               System.out.println("your name is average");
               break;
           }
       case "jason":
           if(name.length()>5){
               System.out.println("your name is not average");
               break;
           }
       }



    }
    public void Dates(){
          System.out.println("Enter a number and we will tell you what month it is:");
          int jay = keyboard.nextInt();
          switch(jay){
          case 1:
              System.out.println("january");
              break;
          case 2:
              System.out.println("February");
              break;
          case 3:
              System.out.println("March");
              break;
          case 4:
              System.out.println("April");
              break;
          case 5:
              System.out.println("May");
              break;
          case 6:
              System.out.println("June");
              break;
          case 7:
              System.out.println("July");
              break;

          default:
              System.out.println("that aint in the month dawg");

          }
    }
}
```

and here is the main class

```
public class Basic  {

    public static void main(String args[])   {
        Methods dateo = new Methods();

        Methods nomalo = new Methods();
        nomalo.Nome();
        dateo.Dates();

    }
}
```

so yea, I am a complete noob. and I am really struggling when learning Java :(  A lot of my friends who started learning java can now make their own 2 games and here I am struggling with a basic concept...

so what is the problem in this code?

Comment: first of all, take the `break;` statements outside the `if` clauses.

Comment: "*so what is the problem in this code?*" ==> you tell us! What does your program do and what would you expect?

Comment: its supposed to ask  the first question and when  I answer that It should ask the next question

Answer (score 1):

Edit - Forget what I said here. Your code is working fine aparently. Just put your 
println before you make the scan.

```
System.out.println("what is your name");
String name = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

So problems is you are reading the data from keyboard before you printed 'what is your name'

The Methods class does not need to extend Basic. the name method does not need to have switch case.

So the Methods class would look like below,

```
public class Methods {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void name(){ 
       System.out.println("what is your name");
       String name = keyboard.nextLine();

       if(name.length() < 5){
               System.out.println("your name is average");
       } else {
              System.out.println("your name is not average");
       }
    }

    public void Dates(){
          System.out.println("Enter a number and we will tell you what month it is:");
          int jay = keyboard.nextInt();
          switch(jay){
          case 1:
              System.out.println("january");
              break;
          case 2:
              System.out.println("February");
              break;
          case 3:
              System.out.println("March");
              break;
          case 4:
              System.out.println("April");
              break;
          case 5:
              System.out.println("May");
              break;
          case 6:
              System.out.println("June");
              break;
          case 7:
              System.out.println("July");
              break;

          default:
              System.out.println("that aint in the month dawg");

          }
    }
}
```